# Calling Controller of Apex Class

Tags: apex, controller, compile-error, constructor

Below is my Apex Class.

```
public class OptySaleTaxCalcController {

    public List<Account_Address__c> AccountaddressList;
    public AcctSeedERP__Sales_Order__c salesOrder;

    public OptySaleTaxCalcController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {...}
}
```

I want to call its constructor from another class. I am trying like below but it errors out. What am I missing?

```
OptySaleTaxCalcController controller1 = new OptySaleTaxCalcController (new ApexPages.StandardController());
```

I get this error:

> Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardController].() at line 11 column 79

Comment: What's the error? Your class is called `OptySaleTaxCalcController` yet you're calling a new `Opportunity` object?

Comment: just updated my original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it backwards; the opportunity needs to be passed to the standard controller:

```
ApexPages.StandarController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Opportunity());
```

From there, pass it to your class:

```
OptySaleTaxCalcController customController = new OptySaleTaxCalcController(controller);
```